# TZinfo Data error in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I keep getting the error below. I have tried a number of things to resolve it including add 'tzinfo-data' to Gemfile. Please help, this is driving me insane:

```
C:/Users/swanster2/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/a
ctive_support/railtie.rb:39:in `rescue in block in <class:Railtie>': tzinfo-data
is not present. Please add gem 'tzinfo-data' to your Gemfile and run bundle inst
all (TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound)
from C:/Users/swanster2/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/
lib/active_support/railtie.rb:36:in `block in <class:Railtie>
from C:/Users/swanster2/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/r
ails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
from C:/Users/swanster2/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/r
ails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
from C:/Users/swanster2/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/r
ails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
from C:/Users/swanster2/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsor
t_each'
from C:/Users/swanster2/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 leve
ls) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from C:/Users/swanster2/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly
_connected_component_from'
from C:/Users/swanster2/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each
_strongly_connected_component'
from C:/Users/swanster2/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
from C:/Users/swanster2/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
from C:/Users/swanster2/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly
_connected_component'
from C:/Users/swanster2/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
from C:/Users/swanster2/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
from C:/Users/swanster2/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/r
ails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
from C:/Users/swanster2/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/r
ails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
from C:/Users/swanster2/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/r
ails/railtie.rb:190:in `public_send'
from C:/Users/swanster2/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/r
ails/railtie.rb:190:in `method_missing'
from hello_world.rb:117:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Edit your post and copy the error message into it. Don't use screenshots for text

Comment: Probably you are missing the `:x64_mingw` symbol for your ruby x64 installation, see [here](https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo/wiki/Resolving-TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound-Errors)

Answer (score 0):

You need to scope the gem for the proper architecture in your Gemfile

```
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: %i[mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby]
```

Comment: `sudo`, `apt`, `apk` with `C:/Users/swanster2/Ruby24-x64/...` good luck with that :)

Comment: @wiesion ops, I forgot about that. Gonna left just the first option. Thanks!